# проверить две таблицы и получить название той, в которой нужное значение(sql)

Tags: sql

Допустим есть две таблицы, при условии что столбцы в них идентичный, но id в них уникален, т.е. в таблице 1 не может быть id который уже есть в таблице 2. У меня есть определенное значение, нужно определить в какой таблице оно находится, пишу запрос с объединением двух таблиц на его поиск

```
SELECT
  t.id
FROM (
  SELECT id FROM table_1
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM table_2
) as t
WHERE t.id = "22"
```

запрос работает, и я могу получить результат - есть данное значение в какой из таблиц или нет. Задача стоит таким образом, я передаю определенное значение и если такое имеется то получить название таблицы в которой оно находится. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Будет вполне уместно, если Вы опубликуете Ваше решение в виде ответа

Comment: можно узнать зачем это надо? Просто странная какая то логика нафига 2 таблицы в этом случае?

Comment: Ну делал многоуровневое меню для сайта, и решил разбить каждую подкатегорию на несколько таблиц, что бы не запутаться, получилось 2 таблицы, так как запись идет в них из написанной на php админки, то предусмотрел уникальный идентификатор id который используется для формирования ссылок, вообщем там мудрено ), я еще в этом новичек и вообщем такую логику придумал , а название нужно для небольшой пагинации ( ну например главная>категория1>категория2 сверху). Там тоже мудрено, на вход передаю идентификатор, по нему по запросу определяю степень вложенности и на ее основе формирую пагинацию

Comment: @varz62 можно было бы конечно сделать одну таблицу и добавить дополнительное поле, в котором бы указывалась степень вложенности ( 1категория > 1.1категория,1.2категория (такая иерархия)) но мне показалось что с двумя таблицами будет проще в том плане что все более структурировано

Comment: не проще сделать таблицу вида id parent_id category есть готовые решения или nested sets для категорйи есть куча отработанных решений

Answer (score 0):

Вывел название таблицы таким образом:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.tablename
FROM (
  SELECT 'table1' as tablename, id FROM table_1
  UNION  SELECT 'table2' as tablename, id FROM table_2
) as t
WHERE t.id = "22"
```